# A way to prevent Windows Update from restarting the computer?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I'm looking for a way to prevent Windows from restarting/installing updates while my program is running.

Currently, I've been setting a registry key which is located in:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

called "AUOptions".  I'm setting this to "2", however this doesn't seem to work in Vista, as my computer restarted last night.  UAC is currently completely off.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the solution just for you personally on your PC only, or for your program which can be potentially running on other PCs?

Comment: This code will run on over 5000 machines.

Comment: This would be a good candidate question for the Beta Super User area.

Comment: Are you looking for a programattic method? If so, this belongs in stackoverflow (and shouldn't have been migrated...)

Comment: Yeah I am looking for a way to do it in C#.  I don't really know why this was migrated. I guess the question is kind of in the middle anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a different registry setting for this:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU

Then set this to 1:

> NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers

I've also put together a [downloadable registry patch for this one](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/prevent-windows-update-from-forcibly-rebooting-your-computer/) if you want that instead.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the way I have Windows Update configured on my computer, it will download the updates but won't actually install/restart them until I choose to do so (as I like to keep my computer on most of the time and don't like having to re-open everything I had opened before the computer restarted).

While potentially extreme, this would be a simple solution to your problem, albeit not a programmatic one.

Comment: I think that is actually what setting the registry key is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a windows forms app or not, but you can cancel a shutdown in the FormClosing event handler of a windows forms app thusly:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

It's possible a windows update will override this, but a normal user shutdown will be prevented by this code (at least in XP).

Comment: if you do this, will the program still remain open?

Comment: Yes, it cancels the shutdown cleanly and leaves the application running.

Answer (score 2):

IMO a better approach would be to study how your application can **automatically re-start** after windows has restarted.

I often left several Visual Studio instances, some explorer windows and some browsers running when I go home and when I'm back the following morning, all the applications are still running. So I think there might be a way to detects and automatically register the application to restart.

I think this might be more documented and easily implemented than trying to prevent windows from ever shutting down.

Comment: The problem is that users will have to log in again before the program would start again.  That isn't acceptable.

Comment: @rwponu I see... can you elaborate a little more on the situation and why this is the desired behavior?

Comment: The program is an alarm clock.  If the computer restarts due to windows update, obviously I'm pissing off quite a few users.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [group policy setting in XP, Vista, and Win7](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/02/11/438009.aspx). Note that gpedit.msc isn't installed on Vista home edition.

Comment: I want to have windows update disabled only while my program is running.  It should start back up when the program is closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution, but a possible one: just kill/stop the service.

You might also (at least this works on Windows XP) change the policy settings using the `gpedit.msc` panel. Don't know if editing the group policies can be done programatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run this process to stop Windows Update completely (at your own peril):

```
sc.exe stop wuauserv
```

Comment: Your answer is without detail and hard to fully understand.  Please consider revising your answer to provide more detail.  For example, what does this process actually do?

Comment: I've made this a wiki.  Please feel free to edit.